# Writing where query using pyspark on SQL table

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, where-clause

I'm querying sql table using pyspark.

If I have a sql table which has two column **(value, isDelayed)** where **"value"** is of double type and **"isDelayed"** has value 0 or 1. How to write a query using pyspark aggregation query which gives sum of "value" when "isDelayed" is 1.

I've already tried below code which is giving an error

```
def __main__(self, data):
    delayedData = data.where(col('isDelayed').cast('int')==='1')
    groupByIsDelayed = delayedData.agg(sum(total))
    return groupByIsDelayed
```

I'm getting

> "Syntax Error: invalid syntax"

on below line

```
delayedData = data.where(col('isDelayed').cast('int')==='1')
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `data.where(col('isDelayed').cast('int')==='1')` with `data.where(col('isDelayed').cast('int') == 1)`

> 2 `=` only (equal operator in python is 2 `=` sign)
>   `1` without quote (because you compare a int, not a string)

#### or

`data.where("isDelayed=1")`